# Symfony - Inheritance mapping and forms

Tags: forms, inheritance, doctrine, parent-child, symfony

I'm facing a problem and I don't know how to resolve it.

With Symfony3 and Doctrine, I'm doing an inheritance mapping with an abstract class (the parent) and 2 child classes. I choose a Single Table Inheritance, so i have one table in my database.
The parent entity is related to an another entity with a ManyToOne relation.

The question is : how do I manage the forms for the inherited entities ? With embedded form ? With form inheritance ?

I try to find an answer but I didn't find a specific example. I hope someone here can give me a clue :)

### **EDIT**:

If I try to schematize, I have an entity `EntityA`. This entity is related to an another entity `EntityB`. This entity `EntityB` has 2 children, `ChildB1` and `ChildB2`. 
The commons attributes are in `EntityB`. Between `EntityA` and `EntityB`, there is a `ManyToOne` relation, so I have an object `$entityB` in my `EntityA` class.

I have a form for the `EntityA` and I don't really know how I'm supposed to integrate the forms for the `EntityB` and its children. 
If I have no inheritance mapping, I use embedded form but with inheritance mapping, I'm confused.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by *"how do I manage the forms for the inherited entities ? With embedded form ? With form inheritance?"*. Using entity inheritance, there's no explicit necessity to also have form inheritance. Also, maybe add a use case as an example of what you need.

Comment: I edited my first post

Comment: I understand the structure but if is still unclear what do you mean by "ow do I manage the forms for the inherited entities"...

Comment: ... added the diagram - correct me if I misunderstood what you wanted to achieve...

Comment: The diagram is correct, thanks. I'm sorry if I'm not clear, the situation is clear in my head in French but it's more difficult in English ^^'
What I'm trying to say is : when you create a form (xxxType.php), it's based on an entity and if I follow my example, I made a form for the "EntityA" (entityAType.php)
and I made a form for the "EntityB" (entityBType.php). 
Because of the ManyToOne relation, I would like to integrate the "EntityBType::class" in the form "EntityAType" like in the official documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html#embedding-a-single-object)...

Comment: .. But the "EntityB" has children. What about them ? I suppose I have to make forms for them too but how integrate them in my "EntityBType" ? And finally in my "EntityAType" ?

Comment: Maybe a note to think about. Forms are not based on entities. It only seems us such because the symfony docs usually use entities as their *data example*. But no where are you forced to map/build/configure your forms to directly represent an entity. You have absolute freedom, and as such there's no need to reproduce the same inheritance structure.